# Why am I losing my first char when trying to an input whie a change state is happening with Vue3?

Tags: vuejs3

I have this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lf395sw/35/) it is basically trying to go from an error state to a good state when the first letter of a string is typed into the input. Here is the code that changes the props on the input event...

```
inputTitle(event){
  this.title = event.target.value;
  this.titleValid = this.title !== "";
},
```

The Problem is because these events appear to be causing some sort of render collision the first typed letter is lost. Is there a way I can avoid the first keystroke getting lost?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code.

First one is `titleValid` cannot be used in TestComponent.

Second one is that your code will trigger a weird behaviour of input field rendering. On first input event, the input field is re-rendered due to change of `valid`. `value` prop remains unchanged and the input field is re-rendered with initial value of `value` which is an empty string. So the first input is cleared. The following input event works because `valid` remains true and the input is not cleared. To solve this, you can pass the input value to `value` prop. You can take a look at ​
https://jsfiddle.net/Lkzs3pax/1